# empty array returned by array_merge mergin a n ampty array with a filled array

Tags: php

This function returns an empty array

```
public function getUsers($distribution){
        $users = array();
        $dist_infos = $this->getDistInfo($distribution);
        foreach($dist_infos as $dist_info){
            $result = $this->storage->executeSQL($dist_info->generateSQL());
            var_dump($result);
            array_merge($users,$result);
        }

        return $users;
    }
```

But i checked that `$result` its not empty ,there is something wrong?

Comment: instead of `array_merge` try `array_push`

Comment: `$result` its an array using `array push`  `$user` would be an array that contains arrays  and this is not that I need.

Comment: what is your expected output here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$users = array_merge($users,$result);
```

OR

```
array_push($users,$result);
```